# If Person is class in java,then what is difference between 1)Person p; &2)Person p = new Person();?

Tags: java, class, object

I am student learning about java.While solving problems I faced the issue.I want to know what is difference between these two statements.

-The second statement is declaration of new object.

-I don't know about the **first statement** and **difference** between two statements.

Also plz let me know when to use both the statements.

If Person is class in java,then what is difference between

1. `Person p;`
2. `Person p = new Person();`

Comment: First is reference

Answer (score 3):

`Person p;` means you create a variable with no person object.
But `Person p = new Person();` means you create a variable and reference it a person object

Comment: Thanks,can you plz tell when to use first statement and when to use second statement?Please elaborate about the first statement & specially when to use it.

Comment: I cant remember that have i ever used the first one so i think it is not very important to use